# How to disable Jacoco test coverage in Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to simply disable Jacoco testcase coverage in my project so that it simply doesn't execute tests and test coverage in my application.

Can anyone help me in that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put `testCoverageEnabled false` on all of your build flavors in your build.gradle

Comment: In 2020, I had to set `isTestCoverageEnabled = false`